# AWS SSM parameter store reliability

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am looking at using [AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) to store secrets such as database connection strings for applications deployed on EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, Fargate docker containers etc).

The linked document states that the service is `Highly scalable, available, and durable`, but I can't find more details on what exactly that means.  For example, is it replicated across all regions?

Is it best to:

a) read secrets from the parameter store at application startup (i.e. rely on it being highly available and scalable, even if, say, another region has gone down)?

or

b) read and store secrets locally when the application is deployed?  Arguably less secure, but it means that any unavailability of the Parameter Store service would only impact deployment of new versions.

Comment: What happens if parameters change?  Like if a password is rotated.

Comment: @myron-semack Secrets Manager will publish an event via CloudTrail - 'RotationSucceeded' when there is a successful rotation. You can use this event to further automate how you want your system to behave in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with the parameter store go with your option a. And fail the app if get parameter call failed. (This happens, I have seen rate limiting happening for Parameter Store API requests) See [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=834134&tstart=0).

Or

The best option is [AWS secrets manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager). Secrets manager is a superset of the parameter store. It supports RDS password rotation and many more. Also its **paid**.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation link.  In my scenario, parameters will be looked up and cached once, and in the case of lambda would take advantage of execution context to store and reference locally. So I hope I wouldn't hit throttling limits.  I'm aware of secrets manager, but don't yet need it,  But I'm still not clear on replication of parameters across multiple regions, e.g. if I have multiple instances of my apps running independently in different regions.  Is there one instance of the parameter store replicated across multiple regions?

Comment: @Joe no, Parameter Store replicates across availability zones within the region, not across regional boundaries.  You can query across regional boundaries but the parameters are not replicated outside the region where you stored them.

Comment: @Joe problem is we could not find the any documentation around rate limiting for SSM parameters. For us it pops up once in a while. We are not a heavy user of SSM as well. Not sure how dependable it is for production loads.

Comment: you can also automate ssm parameters provisioning across regions with Terraform and alike. Then, just read them from whichever region you want.

Comment: you can also use Cloudformation Stack sets - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/aws-cloudformation-supports-multiple-account-and-region-provisioning-with-stackset/

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the unthrottled throughput of SSM. It is not in the spec, but it is ca. 50req/s.

Comment: How did you figure that out? Any Docs?

Comment: Wrote a piece of code that generated a controlled request rate + metrics on the request rate. Tested it with builtin Retry strategy and without :-)